# Action of a 1-form on vector : changing of coordinates - tensor calculus

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, tensors

I try currently to revise my classic. Could you help me please to demonstrate :

$$\frac{\partial T^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^{\prime \alpha}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime \alpha}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}{\partial x^{v}} T^{v}\right)$$

i.e by using a changing of coordinates between $x^{\mu}$ and $x^{\prime\mu}$. $T^{\mu}$ represents the contravariant components of a "vector" (I mean a tensor of rank 1).

This demostration would be the same than proving :

$$T'^{\mu}\text{d}x^{\nu}=T^{\nu}\text{d}x^{\prime\mu}$$

How to justify this equality if I apply a 1-form $\text{d}x^{\mu}$ or another 1-form $\text{d}x^{\prime\mu}$ on a vector $T$ ?

Comment: Isn't really anyone who could give a quick answer ? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a little over-complicated. You have a basis change with coordinate transformation $(x')^μ=C^μ{}_νx^ν$. Accordingly the contravariant tensor $T$ transforms as $(T')^μ=C^μ{}_νT^ν$. Now compute partial derivatives using the chain rule and $x=C^{-1}x'$
$$
\frac{∂(T')^μ}{∂(x')^α}=\frac{∂(C^μ{}_νT^ν)}{∂x^κ}\frac{∂x^κ}{∂(x')^α}=C^μ{}_ν\,(C^{-1})^κ{}_α\frac{∂T^ν}{∂x^κ}
$$

---

Let's try in a larger context. ${\bf T}=T^ν{\bf e}_ν=T'^μ{\bf e}'_μ$ is a vector field in tangent space. The basis vectors are the coordinate derivatives ${\bf e}_ν=\frac{∂}{∂x^ν}$. In that sense one gets by the chain rule
$$
{\bf e}_ν=\frac{∂x'^μ}{∂x^ν}{\bf e}'_μ
$$
which then gives
$$
T'^μ=T^ν\frac{∂x'^μ}{∂x^ν}
$$
Now put parentheses around it and the derivative operator for $x'^α$ before it to get the claimed formula.

If the coordinate change is linear as in the first try, then $\frac{∂x'^μ}{∂x^ν}=C^μ{}_ν$ and
$$
C^μ{}_κ\frac{∂x^κ}{∂x'^α}=\frac{∂(C^μ{}_κx^κ)}{∂x'^α}
=\frac{∂x'^μ}{∂x'^α}=\delta_α^μ
\implies 
\frac{∂}{∂x'^α} = \frac{∂x^κ}{∂x'^α}\frac{∂}{∂x^κ}
=(C^{-1})^κ{}_α\frac{∂}{∂x^κ}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I don't see clearly the right member of my original equation in your expression (I mean $=C^μ{}_ν\,(C^{-1})^κ{}_α\frac{∂T^ν}{∂x^κ}$). We have got to find $=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime \alpha}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}{\partial x^{v}} T^{v}\right)$. Could you make it appear more explicitly please ? Regards

Comment: Do you mean to say that the coordinate transforms are also non-linear? Then you enter the realm of needing a connection form or connection coefficients for a covariant derivative.

Comment: I want just to say that the right member in my original question $=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime \alpha}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}{\partial x^{v}} T^{v}\right)$ doesn't appear clearly in the right member of your expression : $=C^μ{}_ν\,(C^{-1})^κ{}_α\frac{∂T^ν}{∂x^κ}$ . I have difficulties to proove these 2 members are equal. Could you help me please to do the link between both ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it is ok, I had always difficulties with passing tensors

Comment: just a last question : Does the quantity $T'^{\mu}\text{d}x^{\nu}$ or $T^{\nu}\text{d}x^{\prime\mu}$ make sense ? I said that since $T'^{\mu}$ is the contravariant component of vector and $\text{d}x^{\nu}$ is a dual basis vector : so has the product of 2 contravariant quantities sense ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do tensor products of vector spaces without synchronized bases. In that sense, you could do such a thing. But if all tensor factors are either a unique vector space, here a tangential space, or its dual, with the bases always synchronized, then the mixing of coefficients/coordinates in different bases does not make much geometric sense.